# Ratio calculation in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Assume the following numpy array `myArray` is given:

```
myArray = np.array([[4,0,0],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [2,1,0],
                    [0,0,2],
                    [1,3,0],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [1,0,1]])
```

One needs to calculate the ratio between numbers in a column to the sum of the numbers of the column.
For example, the sum of column 0 is 10 so the value in column 0 and row 0 should be 0.4.

That is, the expected result of `myArray` above is:

```
[[0.4,0,0],
 [0.1,0,0.2],
 [0.2,0.25,0],
 [0,0,0.4],
 [0.1,0.75,0],
 [0.1,0,0.2],
 [0.1,0,0.2]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
import numpy as np

myArray = np.array([[4,0,0],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [2,1,0],
                    [0,0,2],
                    [1,3,0],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [1,0,1]])

result = myArray / myArray.sum(axis=0)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[0.4  0.   0.  ]
 [0.1  0.   0.2 ]
 [0.2  0.25 0.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.4 ]
 [0.1  0.75 0.  ]
 [0.1  0.   0.2 ]
 [0.1  0.   0.2 ]]
```

Comment: might want `.sum(axis = 0, keepdims = True)` in case anyone wants to change the axis of normalization.